# Grep String between pattern and copy to new file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am having data in below format and I am trying to capture data between 2 occurrence of string and keep it in a file.

```
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T1` AS SELECT
  aa
  bb
  cc
  dd
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T2` AS SELECT
   aa
   ff
   ee
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T3` AS SELECT   
  aa
  bb
  ff
..
...
..
```

I want output in below format :

FileName T1  should contain :--

```
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T1` AS SELECT
  aa
  bb
  cc
  dd
```

FileName T2  should contain :--

```
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T2` AS SELECT
   aa
   ff
   ee
```

Output filename comes from the value surrounded by backticks

I tried:

```
sed -n '/create statement/,/create statement/p'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '/create statement/{create=$0;next} /CREATE VIEW/{val=$3;gsub("`","",val);filename=val;if(create){print create ORS $0 > filename};next} {print > filename}'   Input_file
```

It will create 3 output files named `T1`, `T2` and `T3` and so on till all the occurrences of T's. If this is not your question then please be clear in your question and add more details on it too.

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now:

```
awk '
/create statement/{
  create=$0;
  next
}
/CREATE VIEW/{
  val=$3;
  gsub("`","",val);
  filename=val;
  if(create){
     print create ORS $0 > filename};
  next
}
{
  print > filename
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^create statement/{ s = $0; n = NR + 1; next }
     NR == n{ t = $3; gsub("`", "", t); print t ORS s > t }{ print > t }' file
```

Results:

```
$ head T[123]
==> T1 <==
T1
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T1` AS SELECT
  aa
  bb
  cc
  dd

==> T2 <==
T2
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T2` AS SELECT
   aa
   ff
   ee

==> T3 <==
T3
create statement 
CREATE VIEW `T3` AS SELECT   
  aa
  bb
  ff
```

Comment: Hi Roman... Sorry If I was not calear .. T1 , T2 , T3 are new files which needs to be created and they will have those content inside it .

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU awk`

```
awk -F'`' -v ORS= -v RS='create' 'NF{print RS $0 > $2}' ip.txt
```

- `` -F'`' `` use backtick as input field separator
- `-v ORS=` empty ORS to avoid extra new line
- `-v RS='create'` use `create` as input record separator
- `NF{print RS $0 > $2}` for non-empty records, print value of RS and input record to file with second field as filename (which will be T1, T2, etc)