# Split a text file using awk

Tags: awk

The sample text file will be like this

```
ID   Z4WTH3_9ACTN            Unreviewed;       182 AA.
AC   Z4WTH3; A0SD0SDF;
AC   Z12SDFG3; ADFFGDF;
DT   11-JUN-2014, integrated into UniProtKB/TrEMBL.
SQ   SEQUENCE   182 AA;  20675 MW;  B85D18AC3B1F0E75 CRC64;
     MNFLEYNKDE KLHFNYKKSC GLWLIVVALI IFAATVIGGK QIINMSVFSF GYVAAFLSIN
//
ID   Z4WXU8_9ACTN            Unreviewed;       203 AA.
AC   Z4WXU8;
AC   QWERDFV1;
DT   11-JUN-2014, integrated into UniProtKB/TrEMBL.
SQ   SEQUENCE   203 AA;  23224 MW;  35F1AE4342F6B3AC CRC64;
     MDCKSIRSEV LWQVVRLREK LMNFLEYNKD EKLCFNYKKS CGLWLIVVAL IIFAATVIGG
//
ID   Z9JHX1_9GAMM            Unreviewed;       132 AA.
AC   Z9JHX1;
SQ   SEQUENCE   132 AA;  13880 MW;  0E09988C0F3ED155 CRC64;
     MKISVDTNVL ARAVLQDDAN QGRSASTLLK DASLIAVSLP CLCELVWILS RGAKLSKEDV
//
```

The actual file is a 100GB file
The file contains only one "ID" line and always start with "ID" line. End with "//"

"AC" line may be multiple. We have to take first element of first "AC" line as filename.

Need to split this file into multiple files based on the "//".
Each file should be named as the text in the line begin with AC.

So the output files will look like

Z4WTH3.txt

```
ID   Z4WTH3_9ACTN            Unreviewed;       182 AA.
AC   Z4WTH3; A0SD0SDF;
AC   Z12SDFG3; ADFFGDF;
DT   11-JUN-2014, integrated into UniProtKB/TrEMBL.
SQ   SEQUENCE   182 AA;  20675 MW;  B85D18AC3B1F0E75 CRC64;
     MNFLEYNKDE KLHFNYKKSC GLWLIVVALI IFAATVIGGK QIINMSVFSF GYVAAFLSIN
//
```

Z4WXU8.txt

```
ID   Z4WXU8_9ACTN            Unreviewed;       203 AA.
AC   Z4WXU8;
AC   QWERDFV1;
DT   11-JUN-2014, integrated into UniProtKB/TrEMBL.
SQ   SEQUENCE   203 AA;  23224 MW;  35F1AE4342F6B3AC CRC64;
     MDCKSIRSEV LWQVVRLREK LMNFLEYNKD EKLCFNYKKS CGLWLIVVAL IIFAATVIGG
//
```

Z9JHX1.txt

```
ID   Z9JHX1_9GAMM            Unreviewed;       132 AA.
AC   Z9JHX1;
SQ   SEQUENCE   132 AA;  13880 MW;  0E09988C0F3ED155 CRC64;
     MKISVDTNVL ARAVLQDDAN QGRSASTLLK DASLIAVSLP CLCELVWILS RGAKLSKEDV
//
```

Comment: please add code you tried... this Q&A is close to what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984857/grep-string-between-pattern-and-copy-to-new-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you on same.

```
awk '/^ID/{close(filename);val=$2;sub(/_.*/,"",val);filename=val".txt"} {print > filename}'  Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd:***
As per OP filename should come from string `AC` so adding following solution too now.

```
awk '/^ID/{close(filename);first=$0 ORS;next} /^AC/{val=$2;sub(";","",val);filename=val".txt";print first $0 > filename;next} {print > filename}'  Input_file
```

OR in case Input_file is NOT having `ID` tags in all sections then we could write `close` function in `AC` tag as follows:

```
awk '/^ID/{first=$0 ORS;next} /^AC/{close(filename);val=$2;sub(";","",val);filename=val".txt";print first $0 > filename;next} {print > filename}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of solution too now:

```
awk '
/^ID/{                       ##Searching string ID here if it is present in any line then do following:
  first=$0 ORS;              ##Creating variable named first whose value is current line with ORS(output record separator).
  next}                      ##next is awk default keyword which will sip further statements.
/^AC/{                       ##Checking here condition if a line contains string AC then do following:
  close(filename);           ##Closing the file which was previously written heer so that we will NOT get too many open files issues.
  val=$2;                    ##Creating variable named val and keeping its value as 2nd field of current line.
  sub(";","",val);           ##Using sub utility of awk to subsitute semi colon with NULL in variable val here.
  filename=val".txt";        ##Creating variable named filename whose value is variable val and .txt(creating output file names here).
  print first $0 > filename; ##Printing variable first and current line in the output file here.
  next                       ##next will skip all further statements now.
}
{
  print > filename           ##Printing the current lines into output file whoever are NOT satisfying the above 2 conditions.
}
'  Input_file                ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```

Comment: This works perfectly. But I need to get filename form line start with "AC".

Comment: @SiyaDiya, please check my 2nd Solution too now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you. I would like to know one more thing. If the line start with AC contains multiple id's seperated by ";" like "AC   Z4WXU8; E9PWJ4; Q6ZQB3; Q8BWI6;", then have to create files with each id and content will be same. like Z4WXU8.txt, E9PWJ4.txt, Q6ZQB3.txt, Q8BWI6.txt etc

Comment: getting the error if the input file is too large(3GB) "awk: cannot open "P0C9S2.txt" for output (Too many open files)"

Comment: @SiyaDiya, I believe that `close(filename)` is for that only, which I had put in my code(thinking the same that you shouldn't get the open files error). It should take care of open files issue. Not sure if your actual Input_file is different than shown one, if yes then there may be a tweak needed in code.

Comment: Would moving the `close` to `/^AC/` block make any difference? If the order of `ID` and `AC` varies, files might be left open.

Comment: @JamesBrown, yes right James sir, that is why I was asking OP if actual file is not having /^ID/ line then we could definitely put `close(filename)` in `/^AC/` tag then.

Comment: @SiyaDiya, please try my 3rd given solution too once and let me know if that helps you on same.

Comment: @SiyaDiya, please do mention your all details in single shot itself else we have to write codes from scratch itself. If needed you could open a new thread also with complete details too.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 no more addition. After the execution of the third solution I found that some files are having only ID and AC line. Nothing after that. So instead of using ID can we use "//" to split the file content? Also in each single file last line should be "//"
I found that the issue is due to the multiple AC line for single entry. I will update the input file in the main question

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have updated the main question and input file structure.

Answer (score 1):

Another using `RS` (GNU awk due to multichar `RS`) to separate records:

```
$ gawk '
BEGIN {
    RS=ORS="\n//\n"          # record separators
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)       # go thru each field in record
        if($i=="AC") {       # once AC found
            f=$(i+1) "TXT"   # next one is the filename
            sub(/;/,".",f)   # replace ; with .
            print > f        # print to file (multiple AC:s lead to multiple files)
            close(f)         # close to avoid problem with too many open files
                             # overwrites files when files with same name
        }
}' file
```

Files:

```
$ ls -l Z*
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 254 Feb 27 09:23 Z4WTH3.TXT
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 254 Feb 27 09:23 Z4WXU8.TXT
-rw-r--r-- 1 james james 202 Feb 27 09:23 Z9JHX1.TXT
```

Inside a file:

```
$ cat Z9JHX1.TXT
ID   Z9JHX1_9GAMM            Unreviewed;       132 AA.
AC   Z9JHX1;
SQ   SEQUENCE   132 AA;  13880 MW;  0E09988C0F3ED155 CRC64;
     MKISVDTNVL ARAVLQDDAN QGRSASTLLK DASLIAVSLP CLCELVWILS RGAKLSKEDV
//
```

Comment: getting error while inputing a 3 GB file "awk: program limit exceeded: maximum number of fields size=32767
 FILENAME="uniprot_sprot.dat" FNR=289522 NR=289522"

Comment: Sounds like your data is not like you described it. At some point there are more fields than you presented. Also, sounds like you're not using GNU awk which, to my undestanding, does not have a field limit. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
awk -v RS='\n//\n' -v ORS= -F'[[:space:];]+' '{print $0 RT > ($7".txt")}' file
```

With any awk:

```
awk -F'[[:space:];]+' '
    $1 == "AC" { out = $2".txt" }
    { rec = rec $0 ORS }
    $0 == "//" {
        printf "%s", rec > out
        close out
        rec = ""
    }
' file
```